# Navigate back to last AMP listing page

Tags: amp-html

I have a long list of products and I want to implement paged navigation for the users to navigate better. What I want to achieve is very similar to [this playground](https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/paged_list/). I created a [demo](https://sleepy-elion-ba838b.netlify.com/) by slightly modifying it and changing AMP.setState for AMP.pushState to push new entries into the browser and be able to navigate back.

As long as I navigate between my 5 pages, the behavior is the expected one. But if I navigate to another url (e.g. by clicking *Go to Google*) and then I navigate back to the AMP again, I always end in the first page of my product list, not in the last one I was when clicking *Go to Google*.

Any help here would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Feature Request (https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/9128) on Github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's currently not supported client-side as there's no way to change the URL in the address bar. You could implement the pagination server-side, which would solve your problem, but results in the whole page being reloaded.

I'd recommend [filing a feature request](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new) on Github.